'android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams android.view.ViewRootImpl.mWindowAttributes' on a null object reference
this is the error happens only when I interact and exit the webview, I return to a previous view of my webview that has a text input field and when I try to interact with it I get this error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field                'android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams android.view.ViewRootImpl.mWindowAttributes' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(23378):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1625)
E/AndroidRuntime(23378):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1869)
E/AndroidRuntime(23378):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4687)
E/AndroidRuntime(23378):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(23378):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(23378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
E/AndroidRuntime(23378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23378):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
E/AndroidRuntime(23378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
I/Process (23378): Sending signal. PID: 23378 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
my webviewinapp this package use
           Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                InAppWebView(
                  key: webViewKey,
                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(transparentBackground: true, clearCache:           true), android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(useHybridComposition: true)),
                  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(widget.urlLyra)),
                  onWebViewCreated: ((InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    webView = controller;
                  }),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),

my customtextfiel
                                  CustomTextField(
                                    key: formKey,
                                    hintText: '0',
                                    enabled: _enabled,
                                    controller: _numberAmountController,
                                    label: '',
                                    obscureText: false,
                                    fontSize: false,
                                    keyBoard: TextInputType.number,
                                    inputFormatters: [
                                      TextInputMask(
                                        mask: [
                                          '\$99,99',
                                          '\$999,99',
                                          '\$9.999,99',
                                          '\$99.999,99',
                                          '\$999.999,99',
                                          "\$9.999.999,99",
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                    maxLength: 13,
                                    changeText: (value) {
                                      // // Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                                      // //   if (mounted) {
                                      // //     validateAllChecks();
                                      // //   }
                                      // // });
                                      // if (value.length >= 5 && value.length <= 12) {
                                      //   setState(() {
                                      //     isActivated = true;
                                      //     //isChangeTextButton = false;
                                      //   });
                                      // } else {
                                      //   setState(() {
                                      //     isActivated = false;
                                      //   });
                                      // }
                                    },
                                  ),

use the globalkey because in other forums indicate that it is not in the tree of the widget the field text input, in the path between view to navigate use
              WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const PrevNavigation(),
                    ),
                  );
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                });
                return;

when exiting the webviewinapp. hope to solve but I didn't get the solution
Help!!!
